# Sort Array, wrong Output

Tags: c, arrays

Today I tried to make a program (algorithm) which search into an Array for the next number which is bigger than preview number found and print it.

The number has to be printed only if the next numbers are not smaller.

**Fist example:**   4,2,3,9,4,6,5: Output should be: 2,3,4,5.

**Second example:** 2,3,6,4,5,1 The output should be 1.

**Third example:**  1,9,8,7,6,5 The output should be 1,5.

Example, if array has the following elements **1,4,2,3,6,4,5,8,6** the output should be:

```
  1 2 3 4 5 6
```

and if array has the following elements **1,4,2,3** the output should be:

> 1,2,3

Here is the program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sortArr(int* array, int n, int next){
    int i,min = array[0];
    int lang;

    if(next==0){
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(array[i]<min){
                min=array[i];
            }
        }
    }

    if(next != 0){
        lang=next;
        while(lang==next){
            for (i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(array[i]<min){
                    min=array[i];
                }
            }

            lang++;

            if(lang== next){
                break;
            }
        }
        min=lang;
    }

    return min;
}

int main(void){
    int a[] = {1,4,2,3,6,4,5,8,6};
    int i,l = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    int next = 0;
    int min = sortArr(a,l,next);

    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        if(min < a[i]){
            if(min < a[i]){
                min = sortArr(a,l,next);
                printf("%d ",min);
            }
            next++;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I think that, the Output has to do with the fact that the program it is working only if the first element is the smallest from the whole array elements.

EDIT:
I tried the following too:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sortArr(int* array, int n, int next){
    int i,min = array[0];
    int lang;

    if(next==0){
        for (i=0;i<n;i++){
            if(array[i]<min){
                min=array[i];
            }
        }
    }

    if(next != 0){
        lang=next;
        while(lang==next){
            for (i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(array[i]<min){
                    min=array[i];
                }
            }

            lang++;

            if(lang== next){
                break;
            }
        }
        min=lang;
    }

    return min;
}

int main(void){
    int a[] = {2,1,3,4};
    /*int a[] = {9,4,2,3,6,4,5,8,6};*/
    int i,l = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
    int next = 0;
    int min = sortArr(a,l,next);

    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        if(min == a[i]){
            continue;
        }

        if(min < a[i]){
            next++;
            min = sortArr(a,l,next);

        }
        printf("%d ",min);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be **2,3,4** but i get **2,2,3,4**.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis Sir, yes. i try somehow to find the algorithm which find in an Array ordered numbers.

Comment: my second approach was almost OK, i think.

Comment: @freenickname, i need an Ordered Array numbers to be printed, so if there is 9,7,2,3,5,4,8,7 the output should be 2,3,4,7. This is what i need.

Comment: Could you explain the objective of the program a bit more clearly

Comment: @SouravKanta if i have "int a[] = {9,7,2,3,5,4,8,7};" expected output is: 2,3,4,7, if i have int a[] = {2,1,3,4};" the expected output should be: 2,3,4.

Comment: @SouravKanta I edited my question, hope is ok now

Comment: why not [`qsort()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/qsort.html)?

Comment: Please define "next biggest number found"

Comment: @Michi shouldn't it for "int a[] = {9,7,2,3,5,4,8,7);" be 2,3,4 instead of 2,3,4,7, if not I can't recognize any logical pattern, if not you should explain the algorithm you are trying to implement first

Comment: @John Coleman my thoughts exactly

Comment: I started to learn c for 7 months now, i wont to learn coding myself. I will understand better the language.

Comment: @aldr, NO i need to print next number which is bigger then the preview one, but the number if is bigger than the next beside the number should be ignored . Why no one understand me, sorry for my bad English

Comment: @Michi ok, now we got one step closer, but why isn't 8 bigger than 4?

Comment: @aldr if we have 2,9,3,8,4 the number 9 is not in he's place is greater then 2 and 3  and should not be printed. The same thing  if we have between 3 and 4 an 8 is have to be ignored because 8 is greater than 3 and 4 so the output should be 2,3,4

Comment: You aren't sorting the array at all, so why have "sort" in the question title?

Comment: ah now I get it you are trying to implement some kind of lookahead behavior searching for the "next smallest" number and ignoring all numbers that a bigger then the "next smallest"

Comment: @aldr Yes, i repeat:  if we have 2,9,3,8,4 the number 9 is not in he's place is greater then 2 and 3 and should not be printed. The same thing if we have between 3 and 4 an 8 , the 8 should not be printed because 8 is greater than 3 and 4 so the output should be 2,3,4

Comment: I really don't see why the output for 2,3,1,4 should start with 2 rather than 1

Comment: @user3121023 Yes, If we have 10,2,6,3,5,9,8,4,7 the output should be 2,3,4,7

Comment: in the above example if we have 10,2,6,3,5,9,8,4,7 and the expected out put is 2,3,4,7, if the question is, why should be 7 also printed? Well because is next number after 4 which is bigger than 4 and we cannot compare that 7 with another next number, because 7 is the last number in the array.

Comment: @Michi There is no need to complicate things,when simple code can achieve the task

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple C code that does the required.The logic is straight forward.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int is_valid(int,int [],int);
void main()
{
 int a[]={1,4,2,3,6,4,5,8,6 };
 int i;
 for(i=0;i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])-1;++i)
 {
   if(is_valid(i,a,sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])))
    printf("%d ",a[i]);
 }
 printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
int is_valid(int i,int a[],int l)
{
 int j;

 for(j=i+1;j<l;++j)
  if(a[j]>=a[i])
   continue;
  else return 0;
 return 1;
}
```

Comment: Well i did already noticed that i made a wrong approach but your code works fine and does what i need.

Comment: if this code works fine then @John Coleman s assumption was applicable and int a[]={2,3,1,4}  starts with a 1 and gives the output 1,4 instead of the 2,3,4

Comment: @aldr Sir, yes, there i made a mistake and created an Unwanted confusion .for 2,3,1,4 the output should be indeed 1,4, Thank you.

Comment: Well i learn fast, but not enough fast. I'm not Young anymore :))

Comment: @Dante Your code fails if i use int a[]={9,2,-1,4,3,7,8,4,3};, the output is -1, 3, 3 and it should be -1, 3, 4, how can i fix this ?

Comment: @Michi But 3 is smaller than 4 and 4 comes before 3.

Comment: @Dante. 4 comes after first 3, because we have already a 3 before 4  ({9,2,-1,4,3,7,8,4,3), so that one should be printed and not the 3 after 4. -1, 3, 4  this is the Output that i need to be printed.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[] = {10,2,6,3,5,9,8,4,7};

   int l = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
   int i,j;
   int check=1;

    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        check=1;
        for(j=i+1;j<l;j++){
            if(a[i]>=a[j]){
               check=0;
            }
        }
        if(check)
            printf("%d",a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Output: `2,3,4,7`

Comment: "error: iteration 8u invokes undefined behavior [-Werror=aggressive-loop-optimizations]|"

Comment: i get wrong output if i use 10,2,6,3,5,9,8,4,7, the output which i get is 2 3 5 4 7, why 5 is there ?

Comment: 5 is bigger than 4 that's why. 2,3,4,7 Should be @sumeet gave me the Answer , please check it,

Comment: Your code fails if i use int a[]={9,2,-1,4,3,7,8,4,3};, the output is -1, 3 and it should be -1, 3, 4. How can i fix this ?

Comment: @Mirchi For the output to be -1,3,3 just change the `a[i]>=a[j]` to `a[i]>a[j]`. The `>=` thing was just avoiding any number if it was repeating in the series.

Comment: I need the output to be -1,3,4 because after 3 we have a 4 in a[]={9,2,-1,4,3,7,8,4,3};. The program ignores the first 3 and read the next one and skips the 4. I need the output to be -1, 3, 4.

Comment: According to the following line in your question: `The number has to be printed only if the next numbers are not smaller.` `4` should not be printed as in the next number there in `a[]={9,2,-1,4,3,7,8,4,3};` is `3` which is smaller than it.

Comment: I understand your logic and is true, but me, I need the output to be -1, 3, 4 because next number after 3 is 4 which is bigger than 3 and should be printed. 3 is not the last bigger number, is 4. The program works if I change  the last 3 with another number. So if i have a[]={9,2,-1,4,3,7,8,4,9}; the output is -1, 3, 4, 9, but if i change 9 with 3 i get -1,3 and should be -1, 3, 4. Hope you understand me.

Comment: @Michi then according to your argument the output of a[]={1,8,1}; be 1,8?

Comment: Yes it should be 1,8 because next number bigger than 1 is 8 in your example and the next after 8 is less than 8 but nut bigger then 1. If you have a[]={1,8,3};  than it should be 1,3. because 3 is less than 8, but bigger than 1.

Answer (score 1):

On edit: tweaked to handle negative numbers.

Here is an answer that implements a `find_next` function which, when you pass it the array, the index of the last found entry and the value of this entry (or 0 in the initial pass) returns either the index of the next entry or the length of the array:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_next(int a[], int n, int i, int p){
    int j,k,min,initialized = 0;
    for(j = i; j < n; j++){
        if(!initialized){
            if(a[j] > p){
                min = a[j];
                k = j;
                initialized = 1;
            }
        }
        else{
            if(p < a[j] && a[j] < min){
                min = a[j];
                k = j;
            }
        }
    }
    return initialized?k:n;
}

int main(void){
   int a[] = {10,2,6,3,-1,5,9,8,4,7};
   int i,j,p, n = sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);

   //find and print first item
   p = a[0];
   i = 0;
   for(j = i+1; j < n; j++){
       if(a[j] < p){
           i = j;
           p = a[i];
       }
   }
   printf("%d ",p);

   //loop using find_next to find subsequent
   i = find_next(a,n,i+1,p);
   while(i < n){
       p = a[i];
       printf("%d ",p);
       i = find_next(a,n,i+1,p);
   }
   printf("\n");
   return 0;
}
```

When run this prints `-1 4 7`

Comment: Yes, the program does what i need.

Comment: Fails if i add -1 like:  10,2,6,3,-1,5,9,8,4,7 i get the same output: 2,3,4,7 when should be -1,4,7

Comment: You never explained how to "boot up" your sequence. You referred to numbers smaller than the previous number but never said what to do when there is no previous number. Since all of your examples without exception involved positive integers I took `p = 0` as a reasonable initial value for the previous argument. In your new example -- in main start with `p = -2`. In general -- let p = min(a) -1. This can easily be determined by a preliminary loop if need be.

Comment: Sir, i know, i just discovered now, sorry. I did not think that it will be different for positive and negative